# troubles loading symfony2 resources

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having troubles loading resources with sf2, the scenario is the following:

```
#app/config/routing_rest.yml
rest_api : 
  type : rest
  resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml"
```

In the rounting_rest.yml, for the moment, I just want to load all the controllers in the @AppBundle/UserInterface/Web/Symfony/Controller/ folder, which all will be for rest purposes, and the only dummy way I found so far to make it work was the following:

```
#src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml
users : 
  type: rest
  resource:     "@AppBundle/UserInterface/Web/Symfony/Controller/UserRestController.php"
  name_prefix:  api_
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put a bundle in a bundle. Either have 2 bundles: AppBundle and UserBundle or put everything in 1 bundle (so you end up with `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml`).

If you don't have plans to use the UserBundle in another project, I would recommend using just one bundle.

Comment: I edited the comment #src/AppBundle/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml was incorrect, my bad sorry. I's not a bundle in another bundle, I'm just trying to load the resource inside my bundle pointing from #app/config/routing_rest.yml